# Autofill a rego number in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I autofill a "rego" number in excel i.e in cell A1 - 0001/2017-18
in cell A2 - 0002/2017-18
Cell 3 - 0003/2017-18

IS this possible with autofill or would I need to look at another approach?

Comment: It would help if you would define your term and explain the result you want. The values you show do not look like numbers, but rather text strings with numeric substrings.

Answer (score 1):

In **A1** enter:

```
=TEXT(ROW(),"0000") & "/2017-18"
```

and copy down.

Comment: I think it should be: `= TEXT(ROW();"0000") & "/2017-18"`. With an semicolon.

Comment: My mistake. With german version of Excel: `= TEXT(ZEILE();"0000") & "/2017-18"`. Why do you think there are differences of function codes in other languages? peculiar

Comment: @Joe6pack . In greek they use a fullstop "." as a thousand separator instead of a comma in everyday language, so they incorporated this into excel.  They also use the semi-colon ";" instead of a comma in a formula. It's fine unless you write everything in an english excel and then open it on a greek excel, it doesn't handle the language change very well